# Spring boot packing from jar to war hibernate sequence has been reset

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using the Spring boot 1.4.2 version from last few month my application is running as jar file and Now I have change it packing to war file. But i am facing one issue i.e

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

has been start from stating again but table has 40+ record. Can any one help me how to fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to hibernate 5. In spring boot 1.4.2 hibernate version has been changed to 5 version. You can used same hibernate sequence using this properties

```
"hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly change your code to use a `SequenceGenerator`. With that you can define an `initialValue` which can be greater than the records already in your table.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=50, allocationSize=1)
```